# NodeJS MailListener

Tags: node.js, imap

I am using this library to read emails from inbox https://www.npmjs.com/package/mail-listener5. But when I select several mails (five mails) as "unread", the event emits 5 times the same 5 mails marked as unread.
Looking inside the library, I found this code which is where the update event is fired. But I can't find a way to make it work correctly.

```
self.imap.search(self.searchFilter, (error, results) => {
      if (error) { self.emit('error', err); } 
      else if (results.length > 0) 
      {
        console.log('results = ',results);

        async.each(results, (result, callback) => {
           
        }, (error) => {
          if (error) 
          {
            self.emit('error', error);
          }
        });
        
      }
    });
  }
```

And this the console out of the code :

```
results =  [ 18140, 18141, 18142, 18143, 18144 ]
results =  [ 18140, 18141, 18142, 18143, 18144 ]
results =  [ 18140, 18141, 18142, 18143, 18144 ]
results =  [ 18140, 18141, 18142, 18143, 18144 ]
results =  [ 18140, 18141, 18142, 18143, 18144 ]
```

The result I expect is

results =  [ 18140, 18141, 18142, 18143, 18144 ]

Thanks for the help..

Answer (score 0):

```
  if (error) {
    self.emit('error', error);
  } else if (results.length > 0) {
    console.log('results = ', results);

    async.each(results, (result, callback) => {
      // Process each result asynchronously
      callback(); // Call the callback function when processing is complete
    }, (error) => {
      if (error) {
        self.emit('error', error);
      } else {
        // Execution reaches here when all results have been processed
      }
    });
  }
});
```

try this callback

Comment: Thanks., but i think the problem is in imap library that raise this event ( the event 'update' ).

Comment: Remember to refer to the documentation or examples provided by the imap library you are using to understand the specific usage and behavior of the 'update' event.